# how to add a location in path environment variable using installanywhere 8 without *.exe file?

Tags: path, environment-variables, installanywhere

i'v look through the documentation but the process is not clear to me. As in windows, my programm's installer is like to do - add it's set-up location to the path environment variable but what would be steps to do so ??
as documentation it would need a variable like this $lax.nl.env.exact_case.Path$ but which isn't working.
Can anyone help to understand or to some references ??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Set System Environment Variable" action.

In "Variable Name" enter `PATH`. This has to be the environment variable name you want to set, not the current value of that variable, which is what `$lax.nl.env.exact_case.Path$` gives you.

In "Set Value To," enter what you want to add to the PATH variable. It could be an expression that includes InstallAnywhere variables (like `$USER_INSTALL_DIR$$/$bin` which evaluates to either `<InstallationDir>\bin` on Windows or `<InstallationDir>/bin` on non-Windows platforms)

Choose whether you want to replace the PATH variable (generally NOT a good idea), or to prepend or append your value to the current PATH variable.

Finally, indicate if this should be for the "Current user" only, or for "All users."

**NOTE**: `$lax.nl.env.exact_case.Path$` may be blank because `$lax.nl.env.exact_case.<Name>$` resolves the EXACT CASE of the `<Name>` variable. Use `$lax.nl.env.exact_case.PATH$` or `$lax.nl.env.Path$`, instead. However, it's always best to use all caps when referring to environment variables. *nix platforms are case sensitive, whereas Windows is not. So, the most compatible form is `$lax.nl.env.PATH$`.